Autofill in react native not working after enabling autofill from settings and adding property in code side

I have developed the application in react native. I have integrated the Autofill in react native iOS, but somehow it is not working i have tried many ways but it won't work.

<View style={styles.otpContainer}>
                    {[0, 1, 2, 3].map((index) => (
                        <TextInput
                            key={index}
                            ref={refs[index]}
                            style={styles.otpInput}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            maxLength={1}
                            onChangeText={(text) => handleInputChange(text, index)}
                            onKeyPress={(e) => handleKeyPress(e, index)}
                            value={otp[index]}
                            autoComplete='sms-otp'
                            textContentType='oneTimeCode'
                            autoFocus={index === 0}
                            onTextInput={(e) => handleAutoFill(e, index)}
                        />
                    ))}
                    {!isVerified && otp.join('').length === 4 && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                        OTP is incorrect please try again later...
                    </Text>}
                </View>


This is my View where i have TextInput

const handleInputChange = (text, index) => {
        let newOtp = [...otp];
        newOtp[index] = text;
        setIsVerified(true);
        setOtp(newOtp);

        if (index < 3 && text !== '') {
            refs[index + 1].current.focus();
        }
    };

const handleKeyPress = (event, index) => {
        if (event.nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace' && otp[index] === '') {
            handleBackspace(index);
        }
    };


This is the methods which i am using for onChange and onKeyPress.

const handleAutoFill = (event, index) => {
        if (event.nativeEvent.autoComplete === 'one-time-code') {
            console.log("In");
            const autoFilledValue = event.nativeEvent.text;
            handleInputChange(autoFilledValue, index);
        }
    };


These are the method where i am handling the Auto fill but it takes only one digit in input.
What should i do ??

I tried adding textContentType='oneTimeCode' this into TextInput but it doesn't work.

Tried handling input change but it won't work.

I tried adding textContentType='oneTimeCode' this into TextInput but it doesn't work.

Tried handling input change but it won't work.


